# Gauss Sums over "semisimple spherical tensor category"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

I read on the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111205v1) the following:

> Let $\mathcal{\mathbf{C}}$ be a semisimple spherical tensor category with simple unit and let
>   $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ be the set of isomorphism classes of simple objects.

Unfortunately I could not read further since I didn't understand the jargon:

- [category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+theory): a collection of objects with morphisms satisfying certain rules.

  - e.g. the category **Set** of Sets and functions between them.
- [tensor category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+category) has a notion of "tensor product" $\otimes$

  - e.g. **Vect** the category of vector spaces and linear maps between them
- [spherical tensor category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spherical+category)

  - A spherical category is a monoidal category with duals that behaves as if its morphisms can be drawn and moved around on a sphere. **Confused**
  - A spherical category is a pivotal category where the left and right trace operations coincide on all objects. **Even more so since I don't know what "pivot" means or why there is left and right "trace"**
- [pivotal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pivotal+category)

  - A pivotal category is an autonomous category equipped with a monoidal natural isomorphism A→(A∗)∗. Pivotal categories have also been called “sovereign categories.” This is a kind of category with duals.
  - E.g. (possibly?)  **Vect** with the duality operation $(V^\ast)^\ast = V$
- [semicimple category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semisimple+category)

  - A semisimple category is a category in which each object is a direct sum of finitely many simple objects, and all such direct sums exist.
  - E.g. Category of representation of a finite group $G$ which have notions of tensor product $\otimes$ and direct sum $\oplus$, so they behave almost like a ring.

---

Another look through the paper suggests I am looking for a [Frobenius algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+algebra), which has zany rules like these:

[image]

Now I can read the second half the sentence:

> If $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ is finite we can define $\dim \mathbf{\mathcal{C}} = \sum_{i \in \Gamma} d(X_i)^2$

Because the category is irreducible every object has a reduction to the direct sum of simple object.  Presumably there is a way to compute these dimensions of these things?  Continuing...

> If $\mathcal{\mathcal{C}}$ is finite dimensional and braided then the Gauss sums of $\mathcal{\mathbf{C}}$ are defined by 
>   $$ \Delta_{\pm} \mathcal{\mathcal{C}} = \sum_{i \in \Gamma} \omega(X_i)^{\pm 1} d(X_i)^2$$
>   where $\theta(X) = \omega(X) id_X$ is the twist of the simple object $X$ defined by the spherical structure.

So I look up [braided monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/braided+monoidal+category) the tensor product $\otimes$ has to satisfy "hexagon rules"...

What is an example of a **finite dimensional braided spherical tensor cateogry** ?  And how do I compute each term in the sum above in such an instance?

Comment: I don't even understand how this corresponds to the classical Gauss sum, if $\mathcal{C}$ is the category of representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ or the appropriate group

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Definitions.**

1. Let $A$ be a finite abelian group. A *quadratic form* on $A$ is a map $q: A \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ such that $q(-a) = q(a)$, and $\langle a, b \rangle = \frac{q(a + b)}{q(a)q(b)}$ is a biadditive form. We call a pair $(A, q)$ a *pre-metric group*.
2. A fusion category is *pointed* if every simple object is invertible. (This implies that the dimension of every simple object is 1. Such a category is necessarily spherical in a trivial way.)

The following theorem is contained (with slightly modified wording) in [Joyal and Street, 1986](http://www.maths.mq.edu.au/~street/JS1.pdf), though the result essentially dates back to Eilenberg and Mac Lane in 1950 (albeit without the language of tensor categories).

> **Theorem.** Given a pre-metric group $(A, q)$, there is a unique braided pointed fusion category $\mathcal{C}(A, q)$ such that
>
> 1. simple objects are indexed by $A$;
> 2. tensor product comes from the abelian group structure of $A$; and
> 3. the braiding on $a \otimes a$ satisfies $c_{a, a}^2 = q(a)$.
>
> Furthermore, every braided pointed fusion category is equivalent to
>   one of this form.

From 3, it follows, that
$$\Delta_\pm \mathcal{C}(A, q) = \sum_{a \in A} q(a)^{\pm 1}.$$
To recover the classical quadratic Gauss sums, take $A = \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z}$ and $q(a) = \zeta^{a^2}$ for $\zeta$ a $p$th root of unity.

A more thorough treatment of Gauss sums for the categories coming from pre-metric groups can be found in Chapter 6 and Appendix A of [*On braided fusion categories I*](http://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0620) by Drinfeld, Gelaki, Nikshych, and Ostrik.

Comment: When are dimensions of simple objects not $1$ or not integers?

Comment: I was missing that these are multiplicative characters $q(x,y) = e^{2\pi i (x^2 + y^2)}$ or such.